# pointer not entering in dispatch_async

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, asynchronous

i am working on threading....i came across this:

```
 -(void)didRecieveResponse:(NSArray*)responseDic{

//Update DB status to '2', which means everything needs to b deleted
[[MediaService sharedInstance] updateMedia:2];
self.projectArray = responseDic;

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{



for (int j = 0; j<[self.projectArray count]; j++) {
 ProjectJsonModel *pModel = [self.projectArray objectAtIndex:j];

     [self parseArray:pModel.imageArray project:pModel ptype:1];

     [self parseArray:pModel.pdfArray project:pModel ptype:2];

     [self parseArray:pModel.videoArray project:pModel ptype:3];


 Media *tmpMedia = [[Media alloc] init];
 tmpMedia.projectId = pModel.projetId;
 tmpMedia.projectName  = pModel.projectName;
// NSLog(@"DB project naem = %@",pModel.projectName);
 tmpMedia.fileType = 4;
 tmpMedia.fileLink = NULL;
 tmpMedia.fileName = NULL;
 //NSURL *fileUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:tmpMedia.fileLink];
 //tmpMedia.fileName = [fileUrl lastPathComponent];
 tmpMedia.status = 4;

 [[MediaService sharedInstance] insertMedia:tmpMedia];
 [tmpMedia release];
 }

   [self checkDbForDownload];


dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {

    //Stop your activity indicator or anything else with the GUI
    //Code here is run on the main thread

});
});
```

which stores all online data into database.and it will displays in app. When it is checking for update application stops working.

In that break point is not entering in this loop, why?

Comment: Which pointer ? Are you talking about the break point step in pointer ?

Comment: I'm confused, where is the pointer? Do you know what a pointer is? Have a read of https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithObjects/WorkingwithObjects.html -1 and voted to close as unclear what the hell you are talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in `dispatch_async` would run asynchronously. Debugging this from outer block of code would step out of the entire `dispatch_async` as a single line and will not step into the code block within. Put an additional break point in `for (int j = 0; j<[self.projectArray count]; j++) {` instead of stepping in from outer block to debug the code. This would stop the asyc background thread to stop when executing.